# Nginx - static directory doesn't work

Tags: nginx, static-files

This works fine by accessing http://localhost

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

But why doesn't it work when I try to access http://localhost/test with this configuration?

```
location /test {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Fails to fetch `/usr/share/nginx/html/test/index.html` or `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`?

Comment: How can I see that?

Comment: What is the path of the file you are attempting to access with `http://localhost/test`?

Comment: Got it. I've created a file /usr/share/nginx/html/test/index.html and now it finds it. But I want it to look at /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `alias` directive:

```
location /test {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

With the `root` directive, the value of the root and the URI are appended together to obtain the path to the file.

With the `alias` directive, the value of the location is removed from the URI first, so `/test/index.html` will be mapped to `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Comment: I hadn't understand the difference between `root` and `alias`. Thanks @Richard Smith